# Parse a JS array and add a style for matching values using .addClass()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm confused as I don't believe I've done anything out of the ordinary here, that I haven't done before.

I'm looking to implement a feature similar to Excel's "Highlight Duplicate Values" action.

I have a function that takes tab separated values and parses them into a list of claims.  It's all hacky, but the "list" (or table) is a series of divs that contains various elements such as a button that holds the claim ID.  Once the list is created and all claims are visible, I parse it to find what buttons hold duplicate values, and apply a class to said button to highlight it using `.addClass()`.

The problem is that I cannot seem to get the button to highlight.  Now I've used functions like this before without any issue, including making a row highlight when clicked (and dim the others), and so on, but I'm confused what seems to be wrong here.

The parsing code is as follows:

```
function parseForDuplicates() { // Look for duplicates to highlight
    var importedListLength = $("div.column.colClaim").length;  // Get length of claims in list

    var claimsToReview = [];  // create an array for below...
    for (let a=0; a < softParsedList.length; a++) {  // Add the claim IDs to the claimsToReview array
        claimsToReview.push(softParsedList[a][0]);
    }

    for (let i=0; i < importedListLength; i++) {  // Compare values...
        var currentCheckedClaimBtn = $(`div.column.colClaim:nth-child(${i+1}) button`);  // Get the button element for current line
            if (i > 0) {
                var previousCheckedClaimBtn = $(`div.column.colClaim:nth-child(${i}) button`);  // Get the button element for previous line only if we're further along the list
            } else {
                var previousCheckedClaimBtn = "none";  // set to "none" if we're at the beginning.
            }
            if (i < importedListLength) {
                var nextCheckedClaimBtn = $(`div.column.colClaim:nth-child(${i+2}) button`);  // Get button element from next line
            } else if (i == importedListLength) {
                var nextCheckedClaimBtn = "none";  // set to "none" if we're at the end
            }

        var currentCheckedClaim = $(`div.column.colClaim:nth-child(${i+1}) button`).val();  // Get claim ID from current line
            if (i > 0) {
                var previousCheckedClaim = $(`div.column.colClaim:nth-child(${i}) button`).val();  // Get claim ID from previous line
            } else {
                var previousCheckedClaim = "none";  // set to "none" if we're at the beginning
            }
            if (i < importedListLength) {
                var nextCheckedClaim = $(`div.column.colClaim:nth-child(${i+2}) button`).val();  // Get claim ID from next line
            } else if (i == importedListLength) {
                var nextCheckedClaim = "none";  // set to "none" if we're at the end
            }

        //console.log(`Previous Claim: ${previousCheckedClaim}`);
        //console.log(`Current Claim: ${currentCheckedClaim}`);
        //console.log(`Next Claim: ${nextCheckedClaim}`);

        if (currentCheckedClaim == nextCheckedClaim) {  // If the current claim matches next claim
            currentCheckedClaimBtn.addClass('duplicateClaim');  // Highlight current button
            nextCheckedClaimBtn.addClass('duplicateClaim');  // Highlight next button
            nextCheckedClaimBtn.addClass('duplicateClaim');  // Highlight next button
            console.log(`${currentCheckedClaim} is a duplicate!`);
        }
        if (currentCheckedClaim == previousCheckedClaim) {  // If the current claim matches previous claim
            currentCheckedClaimBtn.addClass('duplicateClaim');  // Highlight current button
            previousCheckedClaimBtn.addClass('duplicateClaim');  // Highlight previous button
            console.log(`${currentCheckedClaim} is a duplicate!`);
        }
    }
}
```

The CSS in question...

```
.duplicateClaim {
    border-color: #BB9955 !important;
    background-color: #773311 !important;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
```

I've tried with and without `!important` and that doesn't change anything

When I open up DevTools I can see that the styles get applied appropriately, however in the Styles sidebar, the style is nowhere to be found!  I can add it manually to the stylesheet, and at that point, the buttons highlight as intended!

I've gone over the seemingly trivial things: I've definitely *saved* the CSS file.  The HTML file points to the correct CSS file (it never changed to begin with), and there are no conflicting styles that I'm aware of.  I use two stylesheets (one named `style2.css` and the other named `external.css` and there are no conflicts between them.  I tried disabling `external.css` - no change.  I also made sure I didn't somehow open the wrong css (from production or a backup) and just have been editing CSS that was never referenced by changing a DIFFERENT rule - the body - to have a background color that's `#FFFFFF` and it **works**.  I've also tried inserting it directly into the HTML... that doesn't work.  Moving `.duplicateClaim` to the TOP of the CSS file?  Nope.  Maybe I just fat fingered it all?  Nope.  Spelling is correct.  I did a copy/paste just in case my eyes have betrayed my brain - nah, they're still cooperating with me... for now.  And what about adding a class that's actually an ID?

Yeah, no, that period has not magically turned into a hash.  Most definitely has remained a period, and hasn't given me an issue.  Oh oh!  But what about applying the style DIRECTLY too the element?  Nah, I assure you I've tried and nothing wants to play nice.

And lastly, I've tried generating each line WITH the class already entered!  That doesn't work either.  For whatever reason, chrome just seems to eat that one rule for lunch, and it just doesn't exist.  I feel like there is SOMETHING dumb that I'm just not looking at and I'm just dealing with being really, really tired, but I need some kind of sanity check here.  Or, maybe I really *am* going crazy...

Of course, again, let me emphasize that when looking at the source in the developer tools, the class most definitely gets added to the elements that I specify in the code - the JS *appears* to work, regardless of whether or not it's messy and triggers you (however it's not the first time something appears to work but is still wrong.  It just seems like the class ceases to exist the moment the page is loaded.  And if I manually add it in the developer tools by clicking the **New Style Rule** button (the plus next to the :hov and .cls buttons)?  It applies to the correct buttons without issue.

Comment: Can you put the whole thing in a jsfiddle or codepen and add a link? It sounds like a specificity issue tbh

Comment: @Adam I can't isolate the code in a way that would seem to work for a jsfiddle.  As for specificity, the CSS rule doesn't even show up under "Styles" despite existing in the CSS sheet.  The strangest thing is that I can't find a single thing I did differently.